# Finding a set $S \subset \mathbb R$ such that a not a.e. zero function $f$ is lower bounded on $S$

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $f$ be a measurable function such that $f$ is not almost every equal to zero. Does this imply that one can find a set $S \subset \mathbb R$ of positive Lebesgue measure so that
$$
|f(t)| \geq c >0
$$
for almost every $t \in S$ and some $c>0$?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course (actually we can achieve everywhere instead of a.e.). To see this consider the set $S_c :=\{x\in\mathbb R: |f(x)|\geq c\}$. Then on any set $A$ of finite measure we have: If for every $c>0$ we have that $S_c\cap A$ has measure $0$ we get
$$ \int_A |f|\,\mathrm d\lambda \leq \int_A c\,\mathrm d\lambda = c\lambda(A) $$
for any $c>0$, which implies by $c\to 0$ that $f=0$ on $A$ a.e. But as $f\neq 0$ there has to exist a set $A$ of finite measure so that $f\neq0$ on $A$ (as our measure is $\sigma$-finite).

This proves the statement.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. If $S_c = \{t: |f(t)|<c \}$ has measure $0$ for every $c>0$, then $\{t | f(t) \not = 0 \} = \cup_{n\in\mathbb N} S_{\frac{1}{n}}$ as a countable union of measure $0$ set still has measure $0$, we get $f(t)$ is $0$ almost everywhere.